# How to set Oracle's fixedString property in Orion Application Server?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, datasource

I want to set the `fixedString=true` connection property for the Oracle JDBC driver in the datasource definition in [Orion Application Server](http://www.orionserver.com) 2.0.7 (latest stable release).

I've tried the following but didn't work:

```
<data-source
    class="com.evermind.sql.DriverManagerDataSource"
    name="datasource_name" location="jdbc/datasource_location"
    connection-driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username="user" password="pass"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database_host:1521/XE" >

    <property name="fixedString" value="true" />

</data-source>
```

Note: I've managed to set the property in Tomcat 6.0 this way (using the same Oracle JDBC driver, of course):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/datasource_name" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    username="user" password="pass" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database_host:1521/XE"

    connectionProperties="fixedString=true;"

/>
```

But I need to set this in Orion. **How can I do that?**

Comment: I tried to add the "orion" tag but I couldn't due to not enough rep. I'll appreciate if somebody with 1500+ rep adds/creates the tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the oracle application server you have to install OAS 10.1.2.3 has fix for that

Comment: I'm not using OAS, I'm using Orion.